# Error writing plot title using sprintf

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write for each plot their own code.

With the next code I can plot all figures without problem but I can't deal with the tittle.

```
files = dir('*_.mat');

for file = files' %//'
    mat = load(file.name);
    figure;
    plot(mat.lag,mat.acorr);
    title(sprintf('%d',data(:,1)));
end
```

As you can see in the image link, the title contains all the codes  [202,205,...]

[image: sample image]

The codes are located in the first column of variable `data`

Any help would be appreciated!

Best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access one `data` at a time:

```
for ii=1:numel(files)
    file = files(ii);
    mat = load(file.name);
    figure;
    plot(mat.lag,mat.acorr);
    title(sprintf('%d',data(1,ii)));
end
```

Comment: Thank you Shai! It worked! 

But I needed to change the las line of your code to


    title(sprintf('%d',data(ii)));

Because the titles appeared in exponential... 
Thanks again!